# Unable to change alert color in UI Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to change the colors for alerts using UI Bootstrap similar to the example on the the [UI Bootstrap homepage](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). But when I use the code below, the alerts are all in the `alert-warning` color. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AlertFormCtrl as alertForm ">
  <div>
  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alertForm.alerts" type="{{alertForm.alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)" class="text-center">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
  <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click="alertForm.addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
.controller('AlertFormCtrl', function(){
   var alertForm = this;
   alertForm.alerts = [

{ type: 'default', msg: 'Please complete the fields below.' },
  { type: 'success', msg: 'Successfully submitted.' }
  ];

alertForm.addAlert = function() {
  alertForm.alerts.push({type: 'danger', msg: 'Another alert!'});
  };

alertForm.closeAlert = function(index) {
  alertForm.alerts.splice(index, 1);
  };
});
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5erZge41UfDKXz9cFUqf?p=preview)

Comment: Check this http://plnkr.co/edit/b199CIl2N5Vgq2pQsY4P?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace your type from

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alertForm.alerts" type="{{alertForm.alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)" class="text-center">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
```

to

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alertForm.alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)" class="text-center">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
```

In your scope, the object `alertForm.alert` doesn't exist, thus `alertForm.alert.type` is undefined.
So the default type of the alert is used which is **warning**.

You can find the correct version of your Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bfwYBRjwV753VwfqmTNU?p=preview)

Comment: fun fact `alertForm.alerts.$index.type` would work too but not nearly as good as using alert.type

Comment: In fact, `alert` is equals to `alertForm.alerts[$index]`. But using the latter is way less readable.

Comment: for whatever reason not having {{}} around alert.type worked with previous ui-bootstrap, but not in 0.6 ...